# Is $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$ the universal non-Noetherian ring?

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory, noetherian

I recently learnt about the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, x_2,\ldots]$ is an example of a non-Noetherian ring. This example seems like it should in some sense be the "universal example" of a non-Noetherian ring. So, my question is if there is a result stating the existence of a morphism between $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$ and any given non-Noetherian ring, or something along those lines.

Comment: It can't correspond to a non-commutative ring, and a ring could have more than $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ elements. I'm not even sure if we could say for every commutative ring $R$, there is a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[V]$ to $R$ for some set of variables $V$.

Comment: @aschepler Your second sentence is weird, did you mean something else?

Comment: I don't understand the "I'm not even sure": if $R$ is nontrivial, $V$ a singleton, the answer is yes?

Comment: @fosco I should have said surjective. The idea I was trying to get across isn't entirely baked. Also in that case, I guess one variable per element of $R$ works. (I was thinking  earlier infinite sums could be a problem, but they don't come up because of the definition of polynomial rings.)

Comment: well, $\mathbb Z[|R|]\to R$ is exactly the counit of the free-forgetful adjunction, which is an epimorphism because the right adjoint -the forgetful- is faithful (if two ring homomorphisms coincide as set functions, they are the same homomorphism).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is No. Any ring $R$ admits a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\dotsc] \to R$ (just send all $x_i$ to $0$, for example, and use the unique homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to R$). It is also not possible to add reasonable assumptions to this homomorphism which enforce $R$ to be Non-Noetherian or that such a homomorphism needs to exist when $R$ is Non-Noetherian. For example, there is a monomorphism of rings $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\dotsc] \to \mathbb{C}$, but $\mathbb{C}$ is a field and hence Noetherian. If $I$ is some infinite set, then $\mathbb{Z}[(x_i)_{i \in I}]$ is a Non-Noetherian ring, which does not embed into or admit an epimorphism from $ \mathbb{Z}[(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}]$ unless $I$ is countable. The ring $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\dotsc]$ is Non-Noetherian, the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\dotsc]/\langle x_1 \rangle$ is still Non-Noetherian, but the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\dotsc]/\langle x_1,x_2,\dotsc \rangle = \mathbb{Z}$ is Noetherian.  The category of Non-Noetherian rings is also badly behaved, there are no initial or terminal objects. This false impression that $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\dotsc]$ is somehow universal among Non-Noetherian rings probably can be avoided by looking at more examples of Non-Noetherian rings, such as $\prod_{p \text{ prime}} \mathbb{F}_p$ or $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.